# RUN echo -e "deb http ... " prepares a wrong contents of the target file

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Host with **Ubuntu 16.04.2**.

Docker **version 17.06.0-ce**.

**Dockerfile**

```
RUN echo -e "deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ xenial nginx\ndeb-src http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ xenial nginx" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list
```

This results in in **/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list**:

```
-e deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ xenial nginx
deb-src http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ xenial nginx
```

Well, as if interpretation of backslash escapes works. But this "-e" has occurred in the file.

And then such image can't be built.

Could you give me a kick here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try using the `bash shell` for the `echo` command instead. Docker by default uses the `sh` shell and for some reason it doesn't like the `-e` characters and had echo'ed it as part of its input.

To fix this;

**Update to:**

```
RUN bash -c 'echo -e "deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ xenial nginx\ndeb-src http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ xenial nginx" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list'
```

**Outputs:**

> root@87944d07f493:/etc/apt/sources.list.d# cat nginx.list  deb
>   http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ xenial nginx deb-src
>   http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ xenial nginx

You can replicate this "docker problem" by switching to `sh` on your current terminal session and  then do the same `echo` command again.

Comment: Hi, in 2021 I am having this issue and apparently from a Dockerifle I did echo without the -e and the newlines and allworks fine, do you know if is this standard behavour? my run cmd
`RUN echo '.....\n...'`

Answer (score 1):

As Samuel Toh commented, this is  a problem because of Docker using sh for executing  the commands. The problem specifically happens because sh (shell) has a builtin 'echo' command which doesn't accept any flag, not even -h/--help. So it simply prints anything that comes it's way.

You can wrap your call around as suggested with a call to bash, or explicitly ask for the correct version of bash to be used:

```
RUN /bin/echo -e "deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ xenial nginx\ndeb-src http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ xenial nginx" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list
```

The 'echo' binary may be installed at a different place in your docker image, so make sure to check where it is (/bin/, /usr/bin/, etc.) with the help of 'which' and replace it in the command above accordingly.